# How to change the handsontable context menu language

Tags: handsontable

Does anyone know if it is possible to change the HOT default context menu language? Or do I have to create a custom menu that does the exact same thing?

I could not find anything about it over the net.

Thanks,
Lucas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have use `updateSettings` to change the context menu configuration after initialization.

```
  container = document.getElementById('example3');

  settings = {
    data: getData(),
    rowHeaders: true,
    colHeaders: true
  };
  HT = new Handsontable(container, settings);

  HT.updateSettings({
    contextMenu: {
      items: {
        "row_above": {
          name: 'insérer une ligne au-dessus',
        },
        "row_below": {
          name: 'Insérer une ligne ci-dessous',
        },
        "remove_row": {
          name: 'supprimer une ligne',
        }
      }
    }
  })
```